# Is it possible to use SBT in a Java project with Hibernate and AspectJ?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, aspectj, sbt

What would I need to configure and what would automatically work? As far as I understand using both can be a bit tricky, because both use bytecode weaving. Can I keep using the more convenient configuration syntax or do I need the "full" Scala version of it?

Currently I'm trying to use Maven, without much success.

Comment: Are you talking about SBT doing bytecode weaving? If you are, SBT doesn't do that. If you're talking about Hibernate and AspectJ, AspectJ weaves at compile time, Hibernate at runtime, so they won't conflict each other. There is an AspectJ SBT plugin here => https://github.com/typesafehub/sbt-aspectj But I would not recommend you to use SBT without knowing Scala.

Comment: I know that SBT is only a build system. I'm wondering if I can expect less interference with SBT than with Maven between AspectJ and Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you at least provide code examples to work with? What are you trying to achieve?

I have used hibernate - spring - and SpringAOP (which is substitutable for aspectj) and it works well. The same project also worked well with aspectJ - I was trying to intercept calls on specific methods calls in order to determine the exception(s) to serialize back to a GWT client.

Any example and what you intend to achieve is a good start?